# Not able to redirect if Auth::attempt is successful

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a login panel with laravel and finding it difficult to understand why my page is not redirecting to any page

this is the content of my routes.php

```
    Route::get('/myapp/', 'MyApp@index');

    //route to show the login form 
    Route::get('/myapp/login', 'MyApp@login');

    //route to process the login form
    Route::post('/myapp/login', 'MyApp@doLogin');

    //route to show the registration form
    Route::get('/myapp/register', 'MyApp@register');

    //route to process the registration form
    Route::post('/myapp/register', 'MyApp@saveRegister');

    //route to show the reset password page
    Route::get('/myapp/resetpassword','MyApp@resetpassword');

    //route to process the password reset request
    Route::post('/myapp/resetpassword', 'MyApp@doReset');
```

Here is the full code to controller

```
<?php

class MyApp extends BaseController
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('myapp.index');
}

public function register()
{
    return View::make('myapp.register');
}

/**
 * Insert the data into database.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function saveRegister()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    //validate the form data provided by the user
    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
    );
    //now validate the above rules
    $validator = Validator::make($input,$rules);

    //If validator fails send user back to registration form

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()//if validation fails redirect back to registration page
            ->withErrors($validator)//send back all the errors to the form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')//send all data back to form except password
            );
    }

    else
    {
        $password = $input['password'];
        $password = Hash::make($password);
        $myapp = new User;
        $myapp->username = $input['username'];
        $myapp->password = $password;
        $myapp->email = $input['email'];
        $myapp->phone = $input['phone'];
        $myapp->save();
        return Redirect::to('myapp')->with('success','Registration successful');
    }
}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function login()
{
    return View::make('myapp.login');
}

public function doLogin()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
    'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    );

    //ow validate the rules
    $validator = Validator::make($input,$rules);

    //if validator passed

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()//if validation fails redirect back to registration page
            ->withErrors($validator)//send back all the errors to the form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')//send all data back to form except password
            );
    }

    else
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        $userdata = array(
            'username'  => $username,
            'password'  => $password
        );

        //Attempt to do the login
        if($entry=Auth::attempt($userdata))
        {
            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
            return Redirect::to('myapp')->with('message','Success');

        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('myapp/fail');
            /*return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors('message','Wrong username or password')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));*/

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Display the reset password page.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function resetpassword()
{
    return View::make('myapp.resetpassword');
}

public function doReset()
{
    //
}
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

Now my page redirects to myapp/fail which means it is not able to authenticate the data with the data table

Comment: Nothing at all it comes back to same page with username box filled with value

Comment: And you have a route set up to "myapp"?

Comment: Yes I have setup Route to myapp if success else come back to same page. Now I changed it a bit, If it fails it goes to page myapp/fail. and now my login page is redirecting to myapp/fail this means the provided credentials does not match the data in my table. Why ?

Comment: Can you please post your complete Routes.php files and your complete MyApp controller

Comment: Posted the code of my routes and controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the else part**  // if validations ok

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');
$userdata = array(
        'username'  => $username,
        'password'  => $password
);
if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) ....
```

remove `Hash::make` part and get the password as `$password = Input::get('password');`

Comment: Did that but still going to fails page I have provided the data in the users table on the login form but nothign changed

Comment: check the last executed query `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);` place that before redirecting to false and put a `dd();` after that and see the query is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue why my form was not redirecting to the desired page even if the data I was providing was correct. As you can see in MyApp controller I have function named saveRegister which was inserting data into users table after hashing the password I have supplied in the form

```
$password = Hash::make($password);
```

Now in my doLogin function what I was doing is Hashing the password to validate even though the Auth function of laravel hashes the password on its own so I need not to hash my password manually to match it with database.